# Реализация MVC (Процедурный стиль)

Tags: php, mvc

Начал изучать php и по немного пытаюсь разобраться с MVC (до ООП еще не добрался).
Поставил себе цель: сделать простой проект с авторизацией, регистрацией и выводом статей.

Более менее разделив логику получилось так, как ниже.
**Собственно вопрос, логично ли составлен проект?**
Или я где я что не так делаю? (проект работает)

index.php

```
    $routes = explode('/', trim($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], '/'));

$controller = 'authorization';
$action = 'index';

if(!empty($routes[0])){   
    $controller = $routes[0];
}

if(!empty($routes[1])){
    $action = $routes[1];
}

$controller_path = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']."/core/controllers/".$controller.'.php';

if(file_exists($controller_path)){
     include ($controller_path);
}else{
    Error();
}
if(function_exists($action)){
    $action();
}else{
    Error();
}

echo ('<pre>');
print_r(array($controller,$action));
echo ('<pre>');


function Error(){
    header('HTTP/1.x 404 Not Found');
    header("Status: 404 Not Found");
    exit('Страница на которую вы пытаетесь попасть, не существует или была удалена!');
}
```

.htaccess

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php [L,QSA]
```

Контроллеры выглядят так:
core/controllers/authorization.php

```
    function index(){
    include_once ($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/core/views/authorization.php');
}

function check(){
    include_once ($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/core/models/check.php');
}
```

вид таким образом:

core/views/authorization.php

```
    <form action = "check" method = "post">
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td><input type = "text" name = "login"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><input type = "password" name = "password"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><button type="submit" name = "auth-in">Войти</button></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><a href="/registration/">Регистрация</a></td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</form>
```

Модель таким образом:

core/models/check.php

```
    include($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/core/database/connect.php');

if(isset($_POST['auth-in'])){
    if(preg_match("/^[a-z0-9\-]{10,}+$/",$_POST['login'])&&preg_match("/^[a-z0-9]{10,}+$/",$_POST['password'])){
        $stmt = $pdo->prepare("SELECT * FROM users");
        $stmt->bindParam(':login', $login);
        $stmt->execute();
        $result = $stmt->fetchAll();
        print_r($result);
    }else{
        echo('Необходимо проверить данные');
    }
}else{
    echo ('А ты как тут оказался?');
}

if(isset($_POST['reg-in'])){
    echo('модель регистрации');
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Начал изучать php и по немного пытаюсь разобраться с MVC (до ООП еще
>   не добрался).  . . .
>   Или я где я что не так делаю? (проект работает)

Проект-то может и работает. Но, без ООП Вы MVC не построите.

Модели у Вас как таковой нет. Потому, что это структурированный объект, который описывает сущность бизнес логики. То, что у Вас в модели скорее подходит для контроллера.

Контроллеры по принципу 1 контроллер = функция = 1 действие. Для начала может и не плохо. Но, как минимум гибкости у такой архитектуры точно не будет. Для сравнения 1 класс контроллера того же Yii может обрабатывать несколько действий.

К представлению, правда, особых вопросов нет. Но с другой стороны, представление это по большей части вёрстка и JS. А, это совсем другая песня.

В общем как можно скорее добирайтесь до ООП, изучайте как устроены другие MVC фреймворки, используйте полученные знания в собственных проектах и Вы сами увидите, насколько упростится Ваша работа по сравнению с тем, что есть сейчас.